# Rigorous proof of a linear algebra theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I do seek a formal proof for the following statement. 
Let $V$ be a vector space such that $dimV=n$, let $S⊂V$ and let $v_1,...,v_r$ be a basis for $S$, then $S^⊥$ has $n-r$ linearly independepent vectors. 
$$.$$Here I present my proof which is not quite formal.
$$.$$ Since $dimV=n$, then $V$ has $n$ linearly independent vectors, by the Rank-nullity theorem:
$$dimV=dimS+dimS^⊥$$
Furthermore, each element of $S$ is orthogonal to every element of $S^⊥$, then it follows that the set $S+S^⊥$ is linearly independent and thus constitute a basis for $V$. Now, the dimension of $V$ equals the number of linearly independent vectors in that space which is $n$, the basis of $S$ has $r$ linearly independent vectors and hence its dimension is $r$, using the Rank=Nullity theorem we get: 
$$n-r=dimS^⊥$$

Similarly I proved the Rank-Nullity theorem by establishing a linear map on some vector space and etc. I would be very glad if you could share a more rigorous proof of this statement which I find quite interesting, thanks for your time.

Comment: when you say "dimension theorem", do you mean the rank nullity theorem or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Yes it is, it didn't have a name in Serge Lang's linear algebra so I just decided to called it that way for myself, erg shouldn't have done the same in public.

Comment: Just edited the text.

Comment: That's quite fine, and I think "dimension theorem" is standard terminology in some places. The reason I asked is the following: the equation $\dim V = \dim S + \dim S^{\perp}$ is certainly true, but I don't see how you arrived at this equation using rank-nullity theorem

Comment: @peek-a-boo from context it appears to be the orthogonal decomposition theorem rather than the rank-nullity theorem; orthogonal decomposition theorem being the one saying $V=S\oplus S^\perp$.

Comment: @Dave yes I had in mind the decomposition $V = S \oplus S^{\perp}$, so I guess the OP must have misquoted the theorem's name (but if there is a proof using rank-nullity alone, I'd be interested to see it)

Comment: I'm just concerned in proving that given a vector space $V$, and a subset $S$ of $V$ whose basis consists of $r$ vectors, the orthogonal complement of $S$ has $n-r$ linearly independent vectors where $dimV=n$, is this obvious from the rank nullity theorem?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I guess you could get the dimension equation from rank-nullity by getting a surjective linear map $V\to S$ whose kernel is $S^\perp$ (an orthogonal projection, for instance).

Comment: @peek-a-boo , I defined a linear map $L_A:V→U$ and chose a basis for $U$ which is consists of the set ${A_1,...,A_r}$, then I let each $A_i$ be a row vector of the linear map $L$, it follows that the image of $L$ is the set U and the kernel of $L$ is the set of orthogonal vectors to every vector in $U$, hence the $Ker(L)=U^⊥$, from which I get that $dimV=dimU+dimU^⊥$

Comment: @Dave ok sure, but constructing such an orthogonal projection implicitly assumes that we have already shown $V = S \oplus S^{\perp}$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, once you establish the equation
\begin{equation}
\dim V = \dim S + \dim S^{\perp}
\end{equation}
or equivalently,
\begin{align}
\dim S^{\perp} &= \dim V - \dim S \\
&= n - r
\end{align}
there isn't much more to explain; the proof is complete at this point.

To establish this equality, what I'd do is show that we have a direct sum decomposition $V = S \oplus S^{\perp}$, which means $S \cap S^{\perp} = \{ 0\}$ and for every $v \in V$, there exist $x \in S$ and $y \in S^{\perp}$ such that $v = x+y$. This is useful, because whenever there is such a direct sum decomposition, if $\beta_S$ is a basis for $S$ and $\beta_{S^{\perp}}$ is a basis for $S^{\perp}$, then their union $\beta_S \cup \beta_{S^{\perp}}$ will be a basis for $V$ (if this isn't obvious to you, you should attempt a proof). In particular, $\beta_S$ and $\beta_{S^{\perp}}$ are disjoint, thereby giving the equality
\begin{equation}
\dim V = |\beta_S \cup \beta_{S^{\perp}}| = |\beta_S| + |\beta_{S^{\perp}}| = \dim S + \dim S^{\perp}
\end{equation}

Comment: It is very clear, by the way, is $S⊕S⊥$ a standard way to write the sum of two vector spaces?

Comment: And yes, the proof follows directly by the fact both basis are disjoint sets, I wasn't sure that the equality I first established was enough to prove the statement, thanks for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: @Arsene1412 No, this is called a direct sum; this is different from a "regular" sum of subspaces. So if $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$, $U+W$ is called the sum of subspaces, and it equals the set of all $u+w$, where $u \in U$, and $w\in W$. If $U \cap W = \{ 0\}$, we say in addition that the sum of the subspaces $U$ and $W$ is "direct", and we denote this additional information of "directness" with the notation $U \oplus W$

Comment: I see, thanks for the information.